# What programming languages and 3D graphics API pair well together for conducting physics experiments?

Tags: java, opengl, physics, simulation, modeling

I am starting a research project and need to nail down a programming language and 3D graphics API where I will be creating an environment in the field of molecular cell biology where I will be simulating a large range of experiments in silico. The experiments will be done in discrete time and will encompass a complex physics engine. Pretty graphics are not of importance.

I have been spending the last couple weeks researching different options and would like a second opinion before I start implementation.

At the moment I have decided on using Java as the language due to the flexibility, scalability,library/dependency organization (I'm in love with Maven) and other benefits of an OOP language. This project is going to continue to grow and the complexity is going to continue to increase so this is a huge factor for me. I have investigated using Python, and Matlab due to many using these languages in simulations but the lack of maintainability and scalability has always led me back to Java. Most projects I have read using Matlab or Python were also small and/or prototyped so this would have not been a problem for them. I filtered out Python and Matlab due to them being primarily dynamic languages and not being able to scale as well as C++ or Java. I am  a Java guy so that is a bit why I've been leaning more towards Java rather than C++. I want to focus more on the algorithms rather than memory management and library dependencies needed when using C++, however the additional speed of using C++ is a plus.

As for 3D graphics I have decided on OpenGL (and if done with Java would be using JOGL) due to it being so low level where I will have full control, large documentation and community. I have investigated JMonkeyEngine but I think its a bit to bloated for what I really need since it is a game library. I have also had some suggestions of using Maya via Python or C++ but I do not see where there would be any advantage of using Maya. My models will be so heavily dynamic the initial "world" will be almost empty not to mention I am not to concerned with appearance. There is also the question of using a physics engine, this was  part of the reason Maya was suggested to me in the first place. Due to the complexity of the physics involved in my models I am afraid using an existing physics engines I will not have as much control as if I just implemented them my self.

Overall for my application does Java with JOGL sound like a solid path forward? I am thinking that maybe down the road I can do a conversion to C++/OpenGL if needed which I do not think would be too great of a task. This is the first simulation environment I will be creating, am I missing or leaving out any other considerations?
Any thoughts, feedback, input or any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Wil

Comment: Your question is in a gray area that may be considered off-topic or not constructive for SO, and is likely to get closed.  You are asking about programming tools (which is on-topic) but not a specific question about using them.  You might try on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.